# In ADO pipelines how can I pass a filepath via variable to trigger my build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am currently working on a pipeline to push app configs to Azure App Config service. We are taking a mono repo approach with individual json files for various services. I want to create a template where the build will trigger based on the file that was changed.

Example:

```
pool: CP-DEVOPS-EUS-UBUNTU2004-VMSS
trigger:
branches:
include:
- main
paths:
include:
- MY-REPO/FOLDER/My-Service-1.json
```

In the above example when I change My-Service-1.json the build pipeline triggers.

Now if I go to pipeline variables and create a variable called 'TriggerPath' and set it to a file path like below. The pipeline stops triggering.

```
trigger:
branches:
include:
- main
paths:
include:
- $(TriggerPath)
```

If I set the variable in the build pipeline it works. However, I need it to be set as a pipeline variable because I want to create multiple pipelines based on this template for different json files in my config repo. Is there a way to get this to work? If not are there anyways to achieve what I am trying to do without creating a yaml file for each pipeline?

Comment: You can't. Each pipeline should include its own triggers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I have tested, we cannot use variables in `trigger`, no matter with template expression or macro syntax, as mentioned in [Define variables - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch).

###### Trigger single pipeline

If you would expect multiple files to trigger **one single** pipeline to execute a set of steps defined in the YAML file, it is suggested using **wilds cards** to trigger this pipeline by any commit onto the files under certain path(s). In the sample YAML pipeline below, any commit on any file in `FOLDER`  will trigger this pipeline. If you prefer, you can also set different `include`/`exclude` paths or file patterns. See [Build Azure Repos Git repositories - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Learn](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/azure-repos-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#paths).

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
    - main
  paths:
    include:
    - FOLDER/*
```

###### Trigger different pipelines by different paths while referencing the same YAML file

As for your original requirement, you can create multiple pipelines referencing the same YAML file. To set individual trigger for each pipeline, you may consider using UI trigger settings to override the YAML trigger.

[image]

Thus, the two pipelines are created referencing the same YAML file but will be triggered by different file paths.

[image]

Comment: Based on this PathSpecification can I have it trigger different releases?  Because I was initially trying to trigger a build on a specific file and there would be a release associated with that specific build file.

Comment: Also can I access this path specification value in the build that gets triggered?

Comment: So, can I assume you have one single pipeline that is triggered by different file paths and publish different artifacts? I think you may test with the artifact filter of a release pipeline. May I know what you mean by `access this path specification value in the build`? All the files should be from your repo. If you would access the downloading path of your repo onto the agent, you can search in the agent working directory of a self-hosted agent, but we cannot access a Microsoft-hosted agent.